# PHP: filename searching/matching

Tags: php, filenames

How would I go about searching/matching for a paticular set of a characters in a filename, for example 3XYTPRQgz.pdf is the filename, I need to search for '3XYTPRQ', then if this string is found I simply want to output 'job completed', if its not there it will be set to queued. ( I want to do this for more than one file).

My thoughts on how to do this is, (I am struggling on the matching of the string part) :

```
<?php
if(match("7digitnumber) //then < not sure what function to use any tips?
if file_exists($7digitnumber/filename)
{
echo "completed";
}
else
{
echo "queued";
}
?>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to find out if a given string (your case "3XYTPRQ") is part of a longer string ("3XYTPRQgz.pdf") you can take a look at [`strstr`](http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php).

Comment: hey @mqchen was wondering if you could help me on the following: I tried this:  `  $test = strstr($folder,'($row[\'ANALYSIS_NUMBER\'])');
 echo "--$test--"; ` ($folder = /tmp  and analysis_number is a column of values from a table that contain more than one of 3XYTPRQgz ).

Comment: Try changing it to: `strstr($folder,$row['ANALYSIS_NUMBER'])`. By wrapping it with single quotes PHP considers it as a string